# Does sessions x pages/session = pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new Google Analytics and in the past I've used some custom reports to get pageviews but they no longer work due to changes in our website structure.

I'm trying to navigate the standard GA dashboard and can't seem to find pageviews, but can I calculate them by multiplying the # of sessions by the number of pages per sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times yes. Page views can be obtained by multiplying sessions by number of pages per session.

However a session may have 0 page views! For example when sessions have only events. This is unusual in websites, but can be normal if you are using Google Analytics to measure something else.